# Second derivative of a composition?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^p$, $f:\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}$ and define the composition $h(x) = f(g(x))$. The gradient of $h$ with respect to $x$, $\nabla h\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$, is given by
\begin{align}
\nabla h(x) = \underbrace{\nabla f(g(x))}_{1\times p} \underbrace{\nabla g(x)}_{p\times n}
\end{align}

How do I compute $\nabla^2 h(x)$?

Comment: Better write the derivatives as (multi) linear maps. The ordering of the components becomes increasingly complicated. Also, what is your definition of gradient? The factors of the chain rule might be reversed.

Comment: There is something off: $h=f\circ  g$ is a map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, therefore its gradient $\nabla h(x)$ is a $(1\times n)$-matrix (or a $(n\times 1)$-matrix, depending on notations). Moreover: I understand by "$\nabla^2$" you mean (the representation in coordinates of) the second derivative, and not the Laplace operator. Am I right?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yeah, I was wondering if that was correct. I suppose the term $\nabla f(g(x))$ is of dimension $1\times p$? (I've now edited it) And yes, I mean the second derivative by $\nabla^2$. user251257: Thank you, I'll look into multilinear maps.

Comment: @rogerG Notice that, since you opted for $h:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, the second derivative is actually a "$(1\times n\times n)$"-tensor which can be handily represented through the Hessian matrix. Of course, further derivatives incurr in the porblem you observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the first derivative is $D(f\circ g)_x;h\in\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow Df_{g(x)}(Dg_x(h))\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the second derivative is

$D^2(f\circ g)_x:(h,k)\in(\mathbb{R}^n)^2\rightarrow D^2f_{g(x)}(Dg_x(h),Dg_x(k))+Df_{g(x)}(D^2g_x(h,k))\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, if we want to use matricial notations: $[D^2(f\circ g)_x]$ is a $(n\times n)$ symmetric matrix, $[D^2f_{g(x)}]$ is a symmetric $(p\times p)$ matrix, $[Dg_x(h)],[Dg_x(k)]\in M_{p1}$, $[D^2g_x(h,k)]\in M_{p1}$ and $[Df_{g(x)}]=\nabla f(g(x))\in M_{1,p}$. Moreover $[Dg_x]\in M_{pn}$.

We obtain $h^T[D^2(f\circ g)_x]k=h^T[Dg_x]^T[D^2f_{g(x)}][Dg_x]k+\nabla f(g(x))[D^2g_x(h,k)]$.

EDIT 1. Of course, $[D^2g_x]$ is more complicated: it is a stack of $p$ $(n\times n)$ symmetric matrices: $[D^2g_x]=[D^2g_{1x},\cdots,D^2g_{px}]^T$ and $[D^2g_x(h,k)]=[h^TD^2g_{1x}k,\cdots,h^TD^2g_{px}k]^T$. Thus $\nabla f(g(x))[D^2g_x(h,k)]=\sum_{i=1}^p \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}(g(x))h^TD^2g_{ix}k=h^T(\sum_{i=1}^p \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}(g(x))D^2g_{ix})k=h^T(\nabla f(g(x))[D^2g_x])k$.

Conclusion: $[D^2(f\circ g)_x]=[Dg_x]^T[D^2f_{g(x)}][Dg_x]+\nabla f(g(x))[D^2g_x]$. Note that the above matrix is symmetric.

EDIT 2. Answer to @ rogerG . 1. The first derivative is a linear application: $Dg_x\in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^p),Df_{g(x)}\in L(\mathbb{R}^p,\mathbb{R}),D(f\circ g)_x=Df_{g(x)}\circ Dg_x\in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$.

2. The second derivative of a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a symmetric bilinear application: $D^2\phi_x\in BL(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R})$. Its associated matrix is s.t. $[D^2\phi_x]_{ij}=\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x_ix_j}(x)$.
3. Your required formula is a generalization of the formula when $n=p=1$: $(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)g'$ and $(f\circ g)"=(f"\circ g)g'^2+(f'\circ g)g"$.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice answer. You have used some notation that I am not familiar with but it has helped to broaden my knowledge. I have a couple of questions: 1) What does the notation $D(f\circ g)_x:h\in\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow Df_{g(x)}(Dg_x(h))\in\mathbb{R}$ mean? Does this represent a mapping from $h$ to $Df_{g(x)}(Dg_x(h))$? If so, is it saying that the first derivative lives in $\mathbb{R}$? 2) What math have you used here? This seems more general that matrix calculus? Is there a term for the tools you have used? Thanks again!